# Laravel 5: How to count number of items in a relashionship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following table:

- Users

  - id
  - name
- Books

  - id
  - name
  - user_id
  - purchased (bool)

How can I use Laravel to efficiently get all the users and the number of books each user has purchased.

The closest I have got is the following:

```
 $users = User::
        ->with(['books' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('count(*) as number_of_purchased_books')
                ->where('purchased', '=', true);
        }])
        ->get();
 dump($users->toArray())
```

But the above doesn't seem to return anything for the `number_of_purchased_books` property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models). Something like:

```
User::withCount(['books' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('purchased', true);
    }])
    ->get();
```

This method will count related books and will add `books_count` property to each `User` object.

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

Comment: Apologies I am using Laravel 5.1. Any solution for that version.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom relation:

```
public function booksCount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Book')
        ->selectRaw('user_id, count(*) as aggregate_books')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
}

public function getBookCount()
{
    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if (!array_key_exists('booksCount', $this->relations)) {
        $this->load('booksCount');
    }

    $related = $this->getRelation('booksCount')->first();
    // then return the count directly
    return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate_books : 0;
}
```

which can then be used as:
`User::with('booksCount');`

Answer (score 0):

Add user_id to your select to be able to eager_load the books query

```
 $users = User::
    ->with(['books' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(user_id, DB::raw('count(*) as number_of_purchased_books')
            ->where('purchased', '=', true);
    }])
    ->get();
 dump($users->toArray())
```